# How to show own view in Spinner Widget instead of Text View?

Tags: android, layout, view, spinner

I have a selection for some items using a spinner widget. At the moment the spinner will load a simple Textview and show the name of the item.
It is possible to define an own view to show inside the spinner row? I would suspect it being similar to a custom List row.

I simply want to show an individual icon left from the spinner text for each item in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that - as you may know, `Spinner` is a type of `AdapterView`, which means that you can adapt your own data to show in such `View`.

The approach is pretty similar to the one with `ListView`.
Excerpt from ApiDemos:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, INTERPOLATORS);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can define your own layout and pass it to the `SpinnerAdapter` subclass that you use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very easy.

The main thing is that, define TextView as the root element in the layout file.

Do as below:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, INTERPOLATORS);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView>
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20px"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: What if you want to have multiple TextViews in your spinner? Like Google has in the Gmail app?